# How do you put a variable in the array brackets in Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I do an operation like this:

```
self.slider.value = randomArray[0][0];
```

I would like to be able to do this:

```
self.slider.value = randomArray[randomVariable][0];
```

Basically, how do you put that "randomVariable" in the brackets? When I try to do this on Xcode, I get:

> Code: `self.detail1.text = detailsForNotesUse[x][0];`
>
> Error:Expected Method to read dictionary element not found in object
>   of type 'NSArray *'

The variable I put in the brackets is `NSString`, the array is `NSArray`, and `detail1` is a text field.

Declarations:

```
NSString *x = 0;

NSArray *detailsForNotesUse;
```

Comment: Are you trying to access a nested array?

Comment: And x needs to be an int if you're using it as an index. ex. int x = 0;

Comment: No. I am just trying to do what the code in the example shows.

Comment: Thanks! Setting the variable to int worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just reposting the answer I gave in my comment below the question:

*x needs to be an int if you're using it as an index. ex. int x = 0;*

But I'm also writing to note that many of the answers are misleading. You can in fact access a nested array in this way, i.e. `randomArray[x][y];`, because if `randomArray[x]` returns an array (as is syntactically valid in obj-c), the items of that array can then be similarly accessed by appending [y] (though you may have to cast `randomArray[x]` to an `NSArray` to prevent a warning).

Answer (score 4):

You've defined x as an NSString. You should define your index variable like this:

```
NSUInteger x = 0;
```